# i always get the same html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i need some help with this, i'm trying to generate some html with javascript, but always get the same, this is my javascript code

```
var datePickerHTML = function(id){
    var html = "<div id='"+id+"' class='ui-datepicker'>";
    html += "Hello World, my ID is "+id;
    html += "</div>";
    return html;
}

var UhmaCalendar = function(config){
    var dpID = 'dp'+config.inputField;
    this.dpID = dpID;
    jQuery('#'+config.inputField).after(function(){
      return datePickerHTML(dpID);
});
    jQuery('#'+config.btn).click(function(){
          jQuery('#'+dpID).toggle('slow');
    }
}
```

now, in my html i write

```
UhmaCalendar({
    btn : 'countday_pick',
    inputField : 'countday'
});
UhmaCalendar({
    btn : 'sartday_pick',
    inputField : 'startday'
});
```

this is for 2 diferent input and buttons, but they always show the same div with the same text, and id i check the html withthe firebug, only one div is created, ad i want 2 div with diferent ids
i also try with

```
new UhmaCalendar({
    btn : 'sartday_pick',
    inputField : 'startday'
});
```

but is the same, what am i doing wrong here
thanks

Comment: There are several errors in the quoted code that make it unparseable. Any answers you get are likely to be off-target a bit because of it. For instance, `jQuery('#'dbID)` is a syntax error (and there are several non-syntax errors as well).

Comment: None of your eight other questions has received an acceptable answer? None?

Comment: yes, i've received very good responses, but, that has to do that with my question?

Comment: To the left of the beginning of every answer there's a big hollow checkmark. If your question gets answered/solved/whatever, click that checkmark next to the answer that answered/solved it to indicate that the question has been successfully answered (and to give credit to the person giving the answer). If there are multiple answers that solve your issue, choose the best of them (and upvote the others). If you get three effectively identical answers that solve your question, pick the first one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<del>You have forgotten to `return html;` in the function `datePickerHTML`.</del>

With the newest edit, I was unable to reproduce the error. See http://jsbin.com/ucage4 for a demo which works correctly.

Comment: While true, it doesn't explain his symptom (in which he does actually get something). The quoted code is so messed up it's hard to tell what might be wrong...

Comment: I'm going to fix my post, i forgot to putthat but here in my code is correct, but read my post again, this isn't the problem

Comment: @Kstro21: Then please fix all the syntax error. It is difficult to guess what's wrong from some vague symptom and wrong code.

Comment: Fixed the code, i just want to generate div with diferent id for diferent behaivor,

Comment: @Kstro: The fixed code works correctly. (Apart from a missing `)`.)

Comment: just want to generate div with diferents id, then i can give a diferent behaivor

Comment: @Kstro21: *"just want to generate div with diferents id, then i can give a diferent behaivor"* Which is exactly what KennyTM's example does, and demonstrates.

Comment: ok, now i can see the to div in the html but the button is shown always the same div.......

Comment: dame, all that make the diference was this lines var dpID = 'dp'+config.inputField; this.dpID = dpID;

Comment: i don't know what have to do but it fix all, thanks to everyone

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell what's wrong, the code as quoted is unparseable. Some notes that may be of use:

```
var datePickerHTML = function(id){
    var html = "<div id='"+id+"' class='ui-datepicker'>";
    html += "Hello World, my ID is "+id;
    html += "</div>";
    // Should probably have `return html;` here
}

var UhmaCalendar = function(config){
    this.dpID = 'dp'+config.inputField;
    jQuery('#'+config.inputField).after(function(){
      return datePickerHTML(dpID);
                         // ^-- This symbol is undefined, and != `this.dbID`
    });
    jQuery('#'+config.btn).click(function(){
          jQuery('#'dpID).toggle('slow');
                 // ^-- syntax error (and `dbID` is undefined here too)
    } // <-- Missing `);` here
}
```

If I had to guess at the intent:

```
var datePickerHTML = function(id){
    var html = "<div id='"+id+"' class='ui-datepicker'>";
    html += "Hello World, my ID is "+id;
    html += "</div>";
    return html; // tjc
}

var UhmaCalendar = function(config){
    var dpID = 'dp'+config.inputField; // tjc
    this.dpID = dpID; // tjc
    jQuery('#'+config.inputField).after(function(){
      return datePickerHTML(dpID);
    });
    jQuery('#'+config.btn).click(function(){
          jQuery('#'+dpID).toggle('slow'); // tjc
    }); // tjc
}
```

My suspicion is that the `dpID` thing(s) are the main error. I've fixed it above by creating a variable within the function which the enclosed functions inherit access to (because they're closures).

HTH

Comment: i got the same result, the main problem is that, if a call the UhmaCalendar function once, it work perfect, but if i call it twice, i hope it create 2 diferent div, but only one is created, the further down in the code

Comment: did you try the code, is simple, please, try and give some north